# ssh tunnel stopped and started passing HTTPS traffic why?

Tags: https, ssh-tunnel

I have a situation in which an nginx server is on a machine behind a firewall. It has an account `pi` which I can manage things (yes its a raspberry pi - lets call is `server.local`)

I am also on a firewall but I have been able to port forward ssh connections to an external port (am not going to say which) to port 22 on a local machine (lets call is `alpha.local` with an account `gate` which has an `authorized_keys` file with the correct keys in it). lets say that my wan address is `home.example.com`

In order to allow me to ssh into this remote server it has a systemd.service which in essence calls

`ssh -p <my external port> -nNT -R 2200:localhost:22 -R 8442:localhost 443 gate@home.example.com`

Inside my home I can now run `ssh -p 2200 pi@alpha` and end up in a shell in the account of `server.local`

To avoid certificate problems I changed my DNS server to give the ip address of `alphalocal` when requesting `server.local`

Earlier today I could also enter in my browser `https://server.local:8442` and get to the web site that the `server.local` serves.
Then for a large part of the day it would not work with the browser saying there was no network connection.  But again just now it starting working again.

I'm trying to work out why.  I suspect somethings timing out somewhere after a failure of the link (it does occassionally go down and it did for about a minute at midday today)

Any pointers to the problem would be welcome as I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic, just stupidity

I created two bookmarks, one on the toolbar using port 8422 and one in my development tools listing port 8442.  Obviously the toolbar doesn't work whilst the one in the development menu does. Hence the two results.

Strange how I can keep wasting days on such trivialities